# Doctrine - validation with associated entities

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have the following associations with Doctrine:

```
Charge:
  id
  amount
  adjustmentItems

Adjustment
  id
  date
  adjustmentItems

AdjustmentItem
  id
  adjustment
  charge
  amount
```

There are charges, and there are adjustments. Each adjustment is made up of adjustmentItems, which are adjustments to one or more charges.

When adding a new adjustment, I am adding adjustments, and the associated items, via deserialization. Ie:

```
$adjustment = 
   ["date" => "2020-12-14", 
    "items" => [
       ["charge" => 84, "amount" => 600],
       ["charge" => 85, "amount" => 200],
     ]
  ];
```

Everything works well, except I validate the charges using Assert/Valid on the AdjustmentItem::charge.

In the charge validation, I check to make sure the sum of all the adjustments does not exceed the charge amount.

However, Charge::getAdjustmentItems() does not show the just created adjustmentItems (even though the adjustmentItem shows to charge, and persisting everything works as expected).

```
$adjustment->getAdjustmentItems()->first()->getCharge()->getAdjustmentItems()->toArray()
```

is:

```
[]
```

How can I get the Charge to "see" the items from deserialization before persist for validation?

SOURCE:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity\TestFin;

use App\Repository\TestFin\ChargeRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Context\ExecutionContextInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ChargeRepository::class)
 * @ORM\Table(name="`test_financials_charge`")
 */
class Charge
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $amount;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=AdjustmentItem::class, mappedBy="charge")
     */
    private $adjustmentItems;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->adjustmentItems = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getAmount(): ?int
    {
        return $this->amount;
    }

    public function setAmount(int $amount): self
    {
        $this->amount = $amount;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|AdjustmentItem[]
     */
    public function getAdjustmentItems(): Collection
    {
        return $this->adjustmentItems;
    }

    public function addAdjustmentItem(AdjustmentItem $adjustmentItem): self
    {
        if (!$this->adjustmentItems->contains($adjustmentItem)) {
            $this->adjustmentItems[] = $adjustmentItem;
            $adjustmentItem->setCharge($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeAdjustmentItem(AdjustmentItem $adjustmentItem): self
    {
        if ($this->adjustmentItems->contains($adjustmentItem)) {
            $this->adjustmentItems->removeElement($adjustmentItem);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($adjustmentItem->getCharge() === $this) {
                $adjustmentItem->setCharge(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
    
    /**
     * @Assert\Callback
     */
    public function validateBalance(ExecutionContextInterface $context, $payload)
    {
        dd(count($this->adjustmentItems->toArray()));
        if (1) {
            $context->buildViolation('Charge balance (after adjustments) must be greater or equal to $0.')
                ->atPath('invoice')
                ->addViolation();
        }
    }
}
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity\TestFin;

use App\Repository\TestFin\AdjustmentRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=AdjustmentRepository::class)
 * @ORM\Table(name="`test_financials_adjustment`")
 */
 class Adjustment
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $note;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=AdjustmentItem::class, mappedBy="adjustment", orphanRemoval=true)
     * @Assert\Valid
     */
    private $adjustmentItems;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->adjustmentItems = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getNote(): ?string
    {
        return $this->note;
    }

    public function setNote(?string $note): self
    {
        $this->note = $note;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|AdjustmentItem[]
     */
    public function getAdjustmentItems(): Collection
    {
        return $this->adjustmentItems;
    }

    public function addAdjustmentItem(AdjustmentItem $adjustmentItem): self
    {
        if (!$this->adjustmentItems->contains($adjustmentItem)) {
            $this->adjustmentItems[] = $adjustmentItem;
            $adjustmentItem->setAdjustment($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeAdjustmentItem(AdjustmentItem $adjustmentItem): self
    {
        if ($this->adjustmentItems->contains($adjustmentItem)) {
            $this->adjustmentItems->removeElement($adjustmentItem);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($adjustmentItem->getAdjustment() === $this) {
                $adjustmentItem->setAdjustment(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity\TestFin;

use App\Repository\TestFin\AdjustmentItemRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=AdjustmentItemRepository::class)
 * @ORM\Table(name="`test_financials_adjustment_item`")
 */
class AdjustmentItem
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Adjustment::class, inversedBy="adjustmentItems")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $adjustment;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Charge::class, inversedBy="adjustmentItems")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     * @Assert\Valid
     */
    private $charge;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getAdjustment(): ?Adjustment
    {
        return $this->adjustment;
    }

    public function setAdjustment(?Adjustment $adjustment): self
    {
        $this->adjustment = $adjustment;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCharge(): ?Charge
    {
        return $this->charge;
    }

    public function setCharge(?Charge $charge): self
    {
        $this->charge = $charge;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

```
        $json = json_encode([
            "note" => "bla",
            "adjustmentItems" => [
                ["charge" => 1],
            ],
        ]);
        $credit = $this->_deserializeJson($json, Adjustment::class);
        //dd($credit);
        //dd($credit->getAdjustmentItems()->first()->getCharge()->getAdjustmentItems()->toArray());
        $this->_validate($credit);
```

Comment: I guess you have to show your code. Because reasons could be too much - maybe validation group, maybe in controller, maybe you forgot something..

Comment: @UrmatZhenaliev I have added the code

Answer (score 0):

Calling `Charge::addAdjustmentItem` in `AdjustmentItem::setCharge` solved the issue for me.

Anyone know why this is needed?

```
    public function setCharge(?Charge $charge): self
    {
        $this->charge = $charge;
        
        // This is needed so that the Assert/Callback in Charge knows about this adjustmentItem.
        $charge->addAdjustmentItem($this);

        return $this;
    }
```